# Establecer ubicacion de origen de datos en maquina cliente crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente usando crystal report, tengo realizado un reporte en la maquina de desarrollo en la cual funciona sin problema alguno , el problema radica cuando el archivo .rpt es ubicado en la maquina cliente el cual me arroja el mensaje que no se puede abrir la conexión , revisando me percate que en la maquina cliente el servidor de la base de datos dice laptop14hp y en la que desarrollo sistemas-pc , como se ve la imagen que adjunto, con lo cual viene la pregunta como puedo hacer en la maquina cliente cambiar el origen de datos para que funcione sin problema alguno , sin hacer el uso de visual studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional a esto adjunto el código con el cual procedo a visualizar el reporte en el form

```
 private void Frm_Impresion_Presupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = System.Environment.MachineName;

        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DIENTE_SANOS";
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "ODONTOLOGIA";
        myConnectionInfo.Password = "ODONTOLOGIA";
        myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        rd = new ReportDocument();
        ParameterField pco = new ParameterField();
        ParameterFields pfields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pdvc = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pco.Name = "@CODPRE";
        pdvc.Value = SecPre;

        pco.CurrentValues.Add(pdvc);
        pfields.Add(pco);

        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields;
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
        rd.Load("D:/Reporte/Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt");                     
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
    }

    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

    private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
        foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
        {
            tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        }

    }
```

De antemano agradezco sus comentarios y ayuda.

**Actualización:**
Después de verificar las respuestas y probar código actualizo la pregunta y dejo la solución del mismo , lo primero que hice, tome la recomendación que me dieron cree el método en donde ejecuto la sentencia con la petición del parámetro de entrada y posteriormente el llamado en el método load para realizar la llamada del método y ver en reporte los datos que al final deseo visualizar.

```
 public static DataSetImpresionPresupuesto PresupuestoCod(String CODPRE)
    {
        DataSetImpresionPresupuesto ds = new DataSetImpresionPresupuesto();
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_PRESUPUESTO WHERE PRE_COD=@CODPRE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODPRE", CODPRE);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "Buscar_Presupuesto_Edicion");
            return ds;
        }
    }


    private void Frm_Impresion_Presupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {              
        String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                String filePath = @"D:\Reporte\Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt";            
                //Cargar el Reporte
                rd.Load(filePath);                                                                   
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(PresupuestoCod(SecPre));
                //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument 
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " +ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes crear un método que haga el filtro de los datos

```
    public DsReporte FiltrarArticulos(int categoria)
{
    DsReporte ds = new DsReporte();
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Articulo WHERE CatId=@cat";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", categoria);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "Articulo");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Para llenar el reporte solo llamas el método y le envías el dato para hacer el filtro. 
Aquí explico como hacerlo
[Filtrar Datos Crystal Report en .Net](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2013/01/filtrar-datos-de-reporte-crystal-report.html?m=1)

Comment: No se debe responder a la misma pregunta dos veces, en dos respuestas distintas. Si tenias información que agregar, edita tu respuesta anterior y agregala allí.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no definís la cadena de conexión en el archivo de configuaracion App.config(lo agregas a tu proyecto si no lo tienes)

En este archivo podes declarar tu cadena de conexión para cuando lleves tu aplicación a otra pc solo abris este archivo(con el bloc de notas) y cambias ahi tu cadena de conexion

```html
< connectionStrings> 
  < add name="default"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Usuarios.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
< /connectionStrings>
```

Para usar la cadena en tu codigo arias asi

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
{
   //tu demas codigo
}
```

Aqui tenes mas informacion [Archivos de Configuración](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/07/archivos-de-configuracion-una.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        cnn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("reporte_consultas", cnn) With {
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        }
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        cnn.Close()
        Dim CrReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        CrReport.Load("Report/RPentradas.rpt")
        CrReport.SetDataSource(dt)
        Reporviewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = CrReport
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        cnn.Close()
    End Try
        "aquí esta la clave para que tu reporte coja los datos del data Source que defines en tu conexión Sting" CrReport.SetDataSource(dt)
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).